# Proof check: Every compact metric space $M$ has countable dense subset $A$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I just want to check if everything is ok with my proof attempt.

We want to show that there exist some set $A$, such that if given $\varepsilon > 0$ and arbitrary $x$ from $M$ then ball centered in $x$ and of radius $\varepsilon>0$ contains an element from $A$.

So fix some $\varepsilon>0$. Since compact, $M$ can be covered by finitely many balls of radius $\varepsilon>0$. But instead of it, choose $N_\varepsilon \in \mathbb{N}$, $N_\varepsilon = \left \lceil{\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}\right \rceil \geq \frac{1}{\varepsilon}$ and cover $M$ with balls of radius $\frac{1}{N_\varepsilon}$, say $M \subseteq B\left( a_1,\frac{1}{N_\varepsilon} \right)\cup...\cup B\left(a_n,\frac{1}{N_\varepsilon} \right)$. Now, choose arbitrarily points $b_i, b_i \in B \left (a_i, \frac{1}{N_\varepsilon} \right) \cap M$ to be points in $A$. Repeat this for each $\varepsilon > 0$.

Now, countability of this set follows from countability of $\mathbb{N}$ and is dense by construction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set should be countable, of course. Doing this for every $\epsilon>0$ might not yield a countable set. Try doing it for every cover of the form $B(x,n^{-1})$ with $x\in X$ for each $n=1,2,3,\ldots$. Then you'll get a countable union of finite sets, which will be countable. Given now any $\varepsilon >0$ and a point $y\in X$, you want some $x\in A$ such that $d(x,y)<\varepsilon$. It suffices you take $n^{-1}<\varepsilon$, and use the above constructed set.